# What is the Capacity Core Shop used for?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, tales-of-the-abyss

In the Mulkuth Capital in the building where the food, item and equipment vendors are, upstairs there's a Capacity Core Shop, when i talk to the vendor however first a list appears of the core then i have then i cycle though other lists which only the first has Capacity Cores appearing in it with most lines being "-------------------"

Now i'm assuming that i'm comparing the core i have but what is the purpose of this and why doesn't all the cores i have appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I dug up:

> Can you buy Capacity Cores from Capacity Core shops? [...]
>
> No, you can't. Capacity Core shops are pretty much useless, except for the fact that you can see what C. Cores you have and how many (not which) you are missing.

Source: [Gamefaqs Forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/929343-tales-of-the-abyss/38226695)